# SQL fail to insert foreign key constraint

Tags: php, sql

So I have been trying to add notes to my database by using an insert function.
However it gives me the following error:
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`project_blok4`.`notes`, CONSTRAINT `visibility` FOREIGN KEY (`visibility_id`) REFERENCES `visibilities` (`visibility_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

```
public function insert() {
        $errors = [];
        $date = new dateTime();
        $formatted_date = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $author_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $visibility_id = $this->validatedVisibility($errors);
        $title = $this->validatedTitle($errors);
        $description = $this->validatedDescription($errors);
        $student_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'student_id');
        $query =
       "INSERT
        INTO notes (author_id, student_id, creation_date, visibility_id, title, description)
        VALUES (:author_id, :student_id, :formatted_date, :visibility_id, :title, :description)";
      $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
      $stmt->bindValue(':author_id', $author_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $stmt->bindValue(':formatted_date', $formatted_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindValue(':visibility_id', $visibility_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindValue(':student_id', $student_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $stmt->bindValue(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindValue(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $ok = $stmt->execute();
      if (!$ok) {
        $info = $stmt->errorInfo();
        die($info[2]);
      }
    }
```

And here's the html form

```
        <form action="create.php" method="POST">
        <label for="student_id">
            <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="<?= $_GET['student_id'] ?>">
        </label><br>
        <label for="id">Student's name
            <input type="text" value="<?= $note->getStudentFullName($_GET['student_id']); ?>" disabled>
        </label><br>
        <label for="title">Title
            <input type="text" name="title">
        </label><br>
        <label for="description">Description<br>
            <textarea style="width:500px; height: 200px;" name="description"></textarea>
        </label><br>
        <label for="visibility">Visibility
            <select name="visibility[]">
                <?php
                foreach ($visibilities as $visibility) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?= $visibility['visibility_id'] ?>"><?= $visibility['name'] ?></option>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </label><br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: `disabled` input's are not submitted to the server. Remove the `disabled` attribute on your hidden input

Comment: @DarkBee That fixed the issue for my student_id however it still gives me this error: 
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`project_blok4`.`notes`, CONSTRAINT `visibility` FOREIGN KEY (`visibility_id`) REFERENCES `visibilities` (`visibility_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: Please Check Here For form [CLICK HERE](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/attributes-common-to-form-controls.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls)

Comment: may be you want to insert new Note with an inexisting visibility_id

Comment: this is a SQL Server error, it means that the **visibility_id** you are trying to insert, does not exist in the **Visibilities** table, make sure the value is correct